# plot a line graph in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, graph

this is my function for plotting a graph in vb.net how I'm going to replace the ("Jon", 10),("Jordan", 8) with a value that i search from database ?

```
 Private Sub chart_btn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs) Handles chart_btn.Click

 Chart1.Series("Student").Points.AddXY("Jon", 10)
 Chart1.Series("Student").Points.AddXY("Jordan", 8)
 Chart1.Series("Student").ChartType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Bar
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

`Entity Framework` would be a good way to do it. `EF` returns a class object that represents a table. Then you make a `query` and can apply `filters` and get an `IEnumerable(Of {record})` then you can iterate this `List` and supply the parameters from the record. A function would be a better fit for parsing a field and returning a value based on the given string. `EF` simplifies getting your data and placing it in a class/property format so you can use it in code. [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567.aspx) [Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363040/An-Introduction-to-Entity-Framework-for-Absolute-B#)

Example:

```
For Each rec As Record In dbModel.Records.Where(Function(o) o.clientId = clientId).ToList
   Chart1.Series("Student").Points.AddXY(rec.Name, GetYValue(rec.Amount))
Next

Private Function GetYValue(value As string) As Integer
  Dim result As Integer = 0
  Select Case value
    Case "r"
      result = 0
    Case "b" 
      result = 1
    Case Else 
      result = 2
  End Select
  Return result
End Function
```

Comment: sorry i dont understand if let say this is my function >>

Private Function GetValueXY(ByVal strDevice As String, ByVal strTime1 As String, ByVal strTime2 As String) As String

Dim queryString As String = "SELECT Time_stamp, BB_ID, Status, " & _
    '    "(CASE WHEN Status = 'R' THEN 0 WHEN status = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END) AS newstatus" & _
    '    "FROM(dbo.rawdata)" & _
    '    "WHERE (BB_ID = '3100') AND (Time_stamp >= '6/24/2013 8:38:00 AM') AND (Time_stamp <= '6/24/2013 8:38:23 AM')"